# What is the Hauptsatz in "Wenn das Wetter gut ist, machen wir einen Spaziergang."?

Tags: sentence-structure

I learned that V2-Stellung is necessary for a Hauptsatz. We would have to rearrange the Satzgefüge: Wir machen einen Spaziergang.(, wenn das Wetter gut ist).

But in the sentence above, it's V1-Stellung. We could maybe also say:
"Wenn das Wetter gut ist, dann (als Folge der Kondition) machen wir einen Spaziergang."

But starting with 'dann', it's clearly a Nebensatz, right? Besides having V1.

I know certain constructions permit V1 etc, but as I looked over them, I thought that those don't fit here.

Comment: Note the subordinate clause takes position 1, the verb position 2. So, we indeed have V2 word order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this has been asked and answered already, but the upshot is that the verb *is* in V2 position. When a subordinate clause in put first, it counts as the first sentence element, so in the main clause the verb comes immediately after. The subordinate clause is technically part of the main clause, unlike a coordinate clause which is a separate entity.

The possible arrangements are:

- Main clause followed by subordinate clause (suboridnate clause in last postion).

> *Wir machen einen Spaziergang, wenn das Wetter gut ist.*

- Main clause preceded by subordinate clause (suboridnate clause in first postion).

> *Wenn das Wetter gut ist, machen wir einen Spaziergang.*

- Two coordinate clauses with coordinating conjunction

> *Wir machen einen Spaziergang, denn das Wetter ist gut.*

- Two coordinate clauses with adverbial conjunction (adverb in first position)

> *Das Wetter ist gut, deswegen machen wir einen Spaziergang.*

Comment: Excellent answer. As a test, I suppose I could replace the Nebensatz with "Deshalb": "Deshalb mache ich einen Spaziergang". That clears it up.

Comment: @Christelle Augustin - As in the last example. Both *deshalb* and *deswegen* are adverbial conjunctions with about the same meaning as "therefore". Fun fact: "therefore" is an adverbial conjunction in English, so it's supposed to be preceded by a semicolon, not a comma. Not that I've ever followed this rule.

Comment: Das ist gut zu wissen; dieses Wissen werde ich nutzen.